# Optimize rendering of inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have this code :

```
<div v-if="room.expanded">
  <div class="panel position-relative panel-content dates-panel">
    <div class="dates-header d-flex">
      <div class="dates-scroller" :key="`datesHeader`+room.id">
      </div>
      <div class="dates-container">
        <overlay-scrollbars
          :ref="`datesHeader`+room.id"
          :options="datesScrollOptions"
          :data-id="room.id"
        >
          <div class="dates d-flex">
            <div class="month" v-for="(month, i) in dates" :key="month.month+i">
              <span> {{ month.month }} </span>
              <div class="days d-flex">
                <div
                  class="day"
                  v-for="(day, index) in month.days"
                  :key="index+day.d+room.id"
                  :class="{'we': day.w>4, 'wee': day.w>5}"
                >
                  <span class="t">{{ day.t }}</span>
                  <span class="wd">{{ day.d }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </overlay-scrollbars>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="room-data d-flex">
    <div class="headers">
      <div class="header">{{ $t('calendar.roomStatus') }}</div>
      <div class="header">{{ $t('calendar.roomAvail') }}</div>
      <div class="header">{{ $t('calendar.roomPrice') }}
        <span v-if="room.occupancy.std <= 3">
          <icon width="11" height="11"  v-for="i in room.occupancy.std" :key="i+room.id" type="user"/>
        </span>
        <span v-else>
          <icon width="11" height="11"  :key="'icon'+i+room.id" type="user"/> &times; {{ room.occupancy.std }}
        </span>
        <span class="asset" v-html="currencySymbol()"></span>
      </div>
      <div
        class="header restriction"
        :class="{ 'd-none': !isRestrictionShown(rts.id), 'last-shown': lastShownRestriction(rts.id) }"
        v-for="(rts, i) in restrictionOptions"
        :key="rts.id + i">
        <span>{{ rts.text }}</span>
        <icon width="16" height="16" v-b-tooltip:page-calendar.right="rts.tip" type="info"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rows" ref="roomRows">
      <div class="data room-status">
        <div class="day" v-for="(day,i) in data[room.id]"
             :key="day.i+i+room.id" :class="day.avail>0 && !day.csale ? 'bookable' : 'blocked'"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="data room-editable" data-field="avail">
        <div
          class="day"
          v-for="(day,i) in data[room.id]"
          @click.self="focusField($event)"
          :key="day.i+i+room.id"
          :class="day.avail>0 && !day.csale ? 'bookable' : 'blocked'"
        >
          <spinner v-if="isDayUpdating(room.id, day.i, 'avail')"/>
          <div v-else-if="isDayUpdated(room.id, day.i, 'avail')" class="day-updated">
            <icon width="18" height="18" type="ok-tick"/>
          </div>
          <b-input
            :value="day.avail" v-else
            @focus.prevent="selectField($event, day)"
            @mouseup.stop.prevent
            @blur="deselectField"
            @keyup.esc="resetField"
            @change.capture="updateField($event, room.id)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data room-editable" data-field="price" :class="{ 'last-shown': !selectedRestrictions.length}">
        <div
          class="day"
          v-for="(day,i) in data[room.id]"
          @click.self="focusField($event)"
          :key="day.i+i"
          :class="day.avail>0 && !day.csale ? 'bookable' : 'blocked'"
        >
          <spinner v-if="isDayUpdating(room.id, day.i, 'price')"/>
          <div v-else-if="isDayUpdated(room.id, day.i, 'price')" class="day-updated">
            <icon width="18" height="18" type="ok-tick"/>
          </div>
          <b-input
            :value="day.price" v-else
            :disabled="day.avail==0"
            @focus.prevent="selectField($event, day)"
            @mouseup.stop.prevent
            @blur="deselectField"
            @keyup.esc="resetField"
            @change.capture="updateField($event, room.id)"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div
        v-for="rts in restrictionOptions"
        :key="rts.id"
        class="data room-editable"
        :class="{ 'd-none': !isRestrictionShown(rts.id), 'last-shown': lastShownRestriction(rts.id) }"
        :data-field="rts.fld"
      >
        <div
          class="day"
          v-for="(day,i) in data[room.id]"
          @click.self="focusField($event)"
          :key="day.i+i+'day'"
          :class="day.avail>0 && !day.csale ? 'bookable' : 'blocked'"
        >
          <spinner v-if="isDayUpdating(room.id, day.i, rts.fld)"/>
          <div v-else-if="isDayUpdated(room.id, day.i, rts.fld)" class="day-updated">
            <icon width="18" height="18" type="ok-tick"/>
          </div>
          <template v-else>
            <b-input
              class="booking_slot"
              v-if="!rts.cb"
              :value="day[rts.fld]"
              :disabled="day.avail==0"
              @focus.prevent="selectField($event, day)"
              @mouseup.stop.prevent
              @blur="deselectField"
              @keyup.esc="resetField"
              @change.capture="updateField($event, room.id)"
            />
            <check-box
              v-else
              empty
              :value="day[rts.fld]"
              :disabled="day.avail==0"
              @input="updateField($event, room.id, day, rts.fld)"
            />
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So this code is building a kind of calendar for buildings with multiple rooms, for a period, let's say for 30 days.

If we have 5 element for one room = 30 (days) * 5 (elements) = 150 inputs for one room, and if I have 20 rooms = 20(rooms) * 150 = 3000 inputs. The rendering is very slow. Is it possible to reduce this time?

Comment: The user only edits one room at a time. Make the room editable only when the user selects it.

Comment: @tao thank you for the suggestion, you mean that make just one room with inputs ? others rooms will have span's instead of inputs ?

Comment: Yes. Render a simpler component by default, just showing the current values and make it selectable (on click, for example). When selected, you render inputs and allow editing. When blurred, you save the current values and make it simple again.